# How best to unit test a class which uses boost::asio::yield_context?

Tags: c++, unit-testing, boost, boost-asio

I have a class which makes use of boost:asio::yield_context and I'm wondering how best to unit test it.  A simplified version of the class I've got:

```
class Foo {
public:
  void Read(boost::asio::yield_context context) {
      my_scheduler->WaitOnEvent(BUFFER_HAS_DATA, context);
      <...snip...>
      callback(data);
  }

  void Write() {
       // write to buffer
       my_scheduler->FireEvent(BUFFER_HAS_DATA);
  }

  void Start() {
     my_scheduler->Spawn(boost::bind(&Foo::Read, this, _1));
  }
<...snip...>
};
```

I've written my own 'scheduler' which wraps the boost asio functionality, so I have a chance to intercept the calls before they actually hit asio.  It's important that the test be deterministic, so I'd like to be able to have the test use only one thread (so never actually call boost::asio::spawn) and ideally test this class synchronously with some code like this:

```
void do_test() {
    <...snip...>
    unsigned int num_callbacks = 0;
    auto callback = [&num_callbacks] (data) {
        ++num_callbacks;
    }
    foo->SetCallback(callback);

    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
        foo->Write();
        foo->Read(); // What would I need to pass here?
        assert(num_callbacks == i);
    }        
}
```

If I manually create a basic_yield_context, would I be able to pass it to Foo::Read in the test and have it work as expected?  If so, I'm a bit confused as to what the basic_yield_context ctor is actually looking for in this scenario.  If that won't work, I'm really interested in a better strategy for testing this sort of code, what would be the best way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advice would be to use a mock object to mimic the interface of a `yield_context`.

There are a number of libraries you could try for mocking.

A good one to use for boost is turtle:

http://turtle.sourceforge.net/

GoogleMock is another possibility:

https://code.google.com/p/googlemock/

In order to use one of these mocking libraries, you would have to modify your interfaces to accommodate mocks. I think your best bet in this case would be to implement the methods for `Read` and `MyScheduler::WaitOnEvent` so the context parameter's type is a template parameter (i.e. duck-typing):

```
class Foo {
public:

    //! This would be a `duck-type` interface.
    template <typename YieldContext>    
    void Read(YieldContex context) {
        //! You would also need one for your my_scheduler type's call to WaitOnEvent.
        my_scheduler->WaitOnEvent(BUFFER_HAS_DATA, context);
        <...snip...>
        callback(data);
    }      
    <...snip...>
};
```

Comment: In order to do so, my understanding is that I'd have to have the mock derive from the yield_context, and since there isn't an interface (and no default ctor) I'd have to initialize the yield_context, meaning I'd need all necessary arguments to create a yield_context--I was hoping there was a way to avoid that.  Unless maybe I've misunderstood?

Comment: Thanks, Brandon.  I've got a method with the signature: void Read(boost::asio::yield_context context), I'll need to pass something there that is of type boost::asio::yield_context.  Google mock, for example, has mocks derive from the type being mocked, so a non-default ctor would need to be satisfied.  What am I missing?

Comment: You're correct. It does need to derive from it. Also, your signature would slice any such derived object as it passes the context by value. You have a couple of options for the signature, assuming you have control over these. You can either make them take a context by const reference, or you could change them to take a template parameter (like duck-typing.)

Comment: Actually, if you could create a 'duck-typing' interface for `Read`, and the scheduler's method `WaitOnEvent`, that would seem to resolve both issues.

Comment: Hey Brandon, the duck-typing thing would definitely work, good idea.  I wish there was a way that was a bit more straightforward, but maybe this is the best I can do.  I'm also wondering if doing something like leaving the Foo class as is, but not attaching any threads to the io_service and explicitly calling run from my test might be another good way.  Not sure which strategy will be best here yet, I'll have to try them both out.  The duck typing is a good tool to have, I bet that would work well in other situations, too.

Answer (score 0):

Going to mark Brandon's answer as the correct one as 1) it's the only answer I got :) and 2) it's more generic than anything I was able to come up with.

I didn't end up using the duck typing method because it didn't fit all that well with the needs of the asio wrapper I had written.  What I ended up doing was actually continue to let the class use a real io context and a real yield context, but attach no threads to the io context.  I built a pseudo 'timeline' of scheduled events and then played them out as needed by the test so that the results were always deterministic.  It may sound a bit contrived but it was what worked best within the constraints I was dealing with.